# "or" condition causing problems with "if"

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm having trouble with an `or` condition in a function. The `if` statement keeps evaluating as `True` no matter what value `choice` is. When I remove the `or`,  the `if` works correctly.

```
def chooseDim ():
    **choice = input ('Do you need to find radius or area? ')
    if choice == 'A' or 'a':**
        area = 0
        area = int(area)
        areaSol ()

    elif choice == 'R' or 'r':

        radSol ()

    else:
        print ('Please enter either A/a or R/r.')
        chooseDim ()
```

Comment: This gets asked every few hours. `or` conjoins complete conditions, not individual options within a condition. It's not "magical" in that way. This actually stems from a common error in English: it's "either `choice` is 'A' or `choice` is 'a'", _not_ "either `choice` is 'A' or 'a'". Moving "either" would fix it but that's not how it works in most programming languages. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was with you until you called it an *error in English*. Citation needed.

Comment: @kojiro: \*shrug\* I'm a native speaker who's never wrong about anything. How's that? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit better than most StackOverflow answers, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I used an "in" to correct it. It works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

'a' evaluates to True, so you need to construct your if statement correctly.

```
def chooseDim ( ):
**choice = input ('Do you need to find radius or area? ')
if choice == 'A' or choice == 'a':**
    area = 0
    area = int(area)
    areaSol ( )

elif choice == 'R' or choice == 'r':

    radSol ( )

else:
    print ('Please enter either A/a or R/r.')
    chooseDim ( )
```

Answer (score 4):

The answers about `or` itself are correct. You're literally asking if `"a"` is True, which it always is. But there's an alternative approach:

```
if choice in 'Aa':
```

Then again, there's nothing wrong with:

```
if choice.lower() == 'a':
```

Comment: That's actually an approach I've never seen used before - most (including me) go with the standard list, not a string.

Comment: @Volatility Yeah, I instinctively went with a tuple at first, then I realized I was manufacturing an outer immutable iterable to house two single-element internal immutable iterables. That just didn't seem right. :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to just use the `in` operator in this case:

```
if choice in ['A', 'a']: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if choice == 'A' or choice =='a':
```